# If opposite angles in a quadrilateral add up to π, do its four vertices all lie on the same circle

Tags: geometry

I'm struggling trying to find a way to start this problem, I've tried to consider a quadrilateral satisfying the properties and then tried to construct circles around them, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use the Inscribed Angle Theorem.

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/prove-the-opposite-angles-of-a-quadrilateral-are-supplementary-implies-it-is-cyc/115075.

Comment: Okay, I've figured it out now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use inscribed angle theorem.

Let the quadilateral be $ABCD$ and let $m\angle A + m\angle C = \pi$.

Let  $BCD$ be inscribed in a circle $S$.  The arc $BCD$ will have measure $2m\angle C = 2\pi - 2m\angle A$ and so the arc $DAB$ will have measure $2m\angle A$.

By inscribed angle theorem $m\angle A = \frac 12 m$ ARC $DAB$ if and only if $A$ is on $S$.